# Поддержка свойства hover или mouseenter

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Как проверить, поддерживает ли браузер свойство hover (или mouseenter хотя бы)?

А лучше проверка на mouseenter, я столкнулся с тем, что некоторые браузеры, а точнее браузеры моб. устройств не поддерживают это свойство, оно весьма востребовано сейчас, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну еще бы... в мобильном устройстве события мыши - это шикааааарно придумано :D
Собственно, эти свойства неприемлемы для мобильных девайсов :D

Comment: Чет я "перекодил" сегодня, facepalm!

Comment: Угу... ложись спать, закрой вопрос :)

Comment: Ну я бы так не сказал, существуют браузеры и с имитацией курсора. И так эти свойства работают :)

Comment: Есть и кролики без ушей :) Но давайте смотреть на универсальность :) Если девайсы, к которым можно и мышь подключить..... Но давайте оптимизировать под большинство :)